# How to check foreign table permissions on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

does anybody know how to check user permissions for a foreign table on Postgres?

I've tried `\dE` and `\det`, but no luck.

I just want to know who can select, insert, update and delete from a foreign table.

Comment: Have you tried `\dp` ?

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\dp` is a [**psql**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) meta-command which lists tables with their associated access privileges. I believe `\z` is doing the same thing. It also lists privileges for accessing views and sequences.